# I would like to write a typewriter on a chatbot

Tags: javascript

I created a simple chatbot, but when it answers it immediately and it is a bad effect, I would like the bot to make a typing effect, I tried everything but I can not match the typewriter code of the typewriter in the chatbox, it does not work or does not work, you put half the chatbot code:

```
 var messages = [], 
  lastUserMessage = "",
  botMessage = "", 
  botName = 'alex', t
  talking = true; 


function chatbotResponse() {
  talking = true;
  botMessage = "Scusami non ho capito";


    var hi = ['mhhh','ok','se lo dici tu.','come vuoi', 'ho fame', 'Mi sto pulendo il naso... Quello che non ho :(', 'Hai ragione', 'Sei un grande', 'aaahhhhhhh!!!', 'Chi sei?', 'mlmlml', 'haha', 'cavolo', 'wow', 'figo', 'come mai?', 'forse', 'Si', 'No', 'mi piace parlare con te <3', 'spacco bottilia ammazzo familia', 'ti amo', 'ti voglio bene', 'che canzone ti piace?', 'che cantante ti piace?', 'so che pensi che sia stupido ma non lo sono.', 'ma lo sarai tu.', 'va bene', 'bello', 'molto', 'molto bello', 'cosa ne pensi di facebook?', 'xD spacca!'];
    botMessage = hi[Math.floor(Math.random()*(hi.length))];



    var n = lastUserMessage.search(/\b(data|mi dici la giornata di oggi|che giorno è oggi)\b/i);
    if (n !== -1) {
    botMessage = "blabla";
    }
```

obviously in javascript for html, help

Comment: Add a 3s timeout? `setTimeout( ..., 3000)`

Comment: where? I had already done it but it did not work, I'm gonna get something wrong

Comment: `setTimeout( chatbotResponse, 3000)`

Comment: The problem there is that he wants the characters to slowly appear one by one, not to delay the entire message.

Comment: I would like a typewriter effect that works with that code

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is split the message string into an array, and then set an interval that takes one element from the front of the array and prints it after a short delay, like so:

```
function slowType(message) {
  message = message.split("");
  const interval = setInterval(function() {
    process.stdout.write(message.shift());
    if (message.length === 0) clearInterval(interval);
  }, 30);
}
```

This will print one character every 30ms. That's in Node, if you're in the browser you'd do the same thing but updating whatever element rather than `process.stdout.write`.

Comment: meanwhile I thank you, I tried the code, I did not understand what to do